# Value allowing with or without comma's in the text field

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have an amount text field allowing the value as "1,232,454.23", maxlength="12" . Database size is NUMBER(9,2) and it works fine.

When User tries to enter a number 123245444.23 (without comma) text field is allowing additional two digits but the database size is (9,2), getting large number error. How can I allow user enter value with or without comma but stop submitting to the server if the value is large without comma ? Below is regex I have.

```
$.validator.addMethod("verifyDecimalVal", function(value, element) {    
    return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?: 
[\.,]\d+)?$/);
},"Please enter valid amount");
```

Comment: You should be checking the input on the server end, not on the client side, as that can easily be bypassed.

Comment: With the above being said, in your validator, attempt to convert to an int and check if it's the same result, eg: `parseInt(value.replaceAll(",")).toString() === value`   (or parseFloat etc) and then check if it's over your max value

Comment: Thank you both. @freedomn - Can you please give me a sample to validate the value ? Do I need to write another jquery validation ?

Comment: `return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?: 
[\.,]\d+)?$/) || parseFloat(value.replaceAll(",")).toString() === value`  (I'm assuming the callback returns true if it's valid, otherwise change to `!==`) parseFloat as you have decimal places, though your regex *looks like* it doesn't handle them correctly `[\.,]` would allow multiple `.`

Comment: Tried both === and !== . Not working. Value still  allowing . If I understand, you are trying to check the string by removing the ",". But what are we trying to compare ?

Comment: The idea is to convert to an int, then convert back to a string, then compare with the original string (so the ===value should be `===value.replaceAll(",")` as well).    In the console run this `parseFloat("12345678901234567890").toString()` - you'll see it = `12345678901234567000` which is not the same as the original.   Similarly: `parseFloat("123456789012345678901234567890").toString()` outputs in a different format.

Comment: I want to remove "," from the string and check the length of characters before "." and the if it is greater than 7, I need to stop. I want to write a sperate validation. Can you please modify this ? $.validator.addMethod('checkVal', function(value, element, param) {
    return value == (value.replaceAll(",")).length() > 7;
}, 'Please enter a valid Amount');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253992/discussion-between-user3067524-and-freedomn-m).

Comment: I ended up doing the this as I could not figure from addMthod.  var amount = $('#amountDue').val();  
  amount = amount.replace(/\,/g, '');
  
  if(amount.length > 10){
   $('#alertModal').modal('show')
  }